# Move the Bishop

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given an n × m chessboard, a bishop and two numbers a and b.Initially bishop is placed on the position (i, j) on the board.There can only be actions of the following types:

```
move the Bishop from position (x, y) on the board to position (x - a, y - b)
move the Bishop from position (x, y) on the board to position (x + a, y - b)
move the Bishop from position (x, y) on the board to position (x - a, y + b)
move the Bishop from position (x, y) on the board to position (x + a, y + b).
```

I want to find the minimum number of allowed actions that are needed to be performed to move the bishop from the initial position (i, j) to one of the chessboard corners and when it is not possible?

Comment: It is neither, @Xoff.  It's modular arithmetic combined with parity concerns.

Comment: @Aaron. I agree this is more simple to see it as some kind of arithmetic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the possible corners that a bishop can travel to, depending on the color pattern on the chessboard.  Then, if one can get to a corner $(x',y')$, then

$x\equiv x'\pmod{a}$,  and $y\equiv y'\pmod{b}$ $ ~~~~$(*)

The reason is that all four possible moves preserve the $x$ coordinate $\pmod{a}$, and the $y$ coordinate $\pmod{b}$.  So in order to get to $(x',y')$, the conditions of (*) must both hold.  (similarly for the other corner).

Now suppose that the conditions hold.  Then $x-x'=sa$ and $y-y'=tb$, for some integers $s,t$.  Note that the four moves all preserve the parity of $m+n$.  The final position has $s+t=0$, so if the initial position has $s+t$ odd, the position can't be solved.  If instead the initial position has $s+t$ even, then the position can be solved, using $\max(|s|,|t|)$ moves, as follows.  Without loss suppose that $|t|\ge |s|$, and that $t>0$.  Each move will decrease $t$ by one.  Initially, we move $s$ to approach $0$; once it gets there then we alternate moving $s$ back one step, then again to $0$, until $t$ finally arrives at $0$.

---

Worked example, as requested, for $n=5, m=7, i=1, j=3, a=2, b=2$

Suppose we color the board so that the bishop begins on a black square.  As it happens, all four corners are black.  Considering the $(1,1)$ corner, we have $i-1=0a$ and $j-1=1b$.  Since $0+1$ is odd, we cannot reach that corner.  Considering the $(7,1)$ corner, we have $i-7=-3a$ and $j-1=1b$.  Since $-3+1$ is even, we can reach the corner.  It takes 3 steps, where we increase the x-coordinate at each step.  The y-coordinate first goes down (to its minimum), then back up, then down again.  Considering the $(1,5)$ corner, we have $i-1=0a, j-5=-1b$.  Since $0+(-1)$ is odd, we cannot reach that corner.  Lastly, considering the $(7,5)$ corner, we have $i-7=-3a, j-5=-1b$.  Since $-3+(-1)$ is even, we can reach the corner, again in 3 steps.

Comment: their is only one bishop.and is the answer independent of n and m of chessboard?

Comment: for given n,m,i,j,a,b what formula could u derive?

Comment: The answer is not independent of $m,n$.  As you vary $m,n$, the corners accessible to the bishop vary.  If the bishop is on a black square, it can go to the two black corners only.

Comment: could u explain ur explanation for n=5 m=7 i=1 j=3 a=2 b=2?

Comment: But we can move the bishop first to position (1 + 2, 3 + 2) = (3, 5), from there can move it to positions (3 - 2, 5 + 2) = (1, 7) and (3 + 2, 5 + 2) = (5, 7) which are both the corners.So moves required are 2 and not 3

Comment: @vadmin123 and even according to explanation..should n't the moves be max(|s|,|t|)?or m i wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my first version had $m,n$ instead of $s,t$, and when I made the change those slipped through the cracks.

Comment: but the answer is still wrong..

Comment: The bishops are not normal chess bishops, and this is not a normal chess board, so black/white has nothing to do with it.  It is definitely possible to reach all 4 corner, for example when $n=m=3$ and $a=b=1$.

Comment: @vadim123 Your explanation is incorrect

Comment: My answer is correct, and includes both a proof and a worked example.  What else do you want?

Comment: @vadim123 But we can move the bishop first to position (1 + 2, 3 + 2) = (3, 5), from there can move it to positions (3 - 2, 5 + 2) = (1, 7) and (3 + 2, 5 + 2) = (5, 7) which are both the corners.So moves required are 2 and not 3 .Your xplanation gives 3 as answer but we can see it in 2 moves

Comment: @vadim123 we need MINIMUM moves

Comment: The issue is that I have the board going from $(1,1)$ to $(7,5)$, while you have the board going from $(1,1)$ to $(5,7)$.